# can NOT access default S3 bucket in near-lake-farmework-py

Tags: nearprotocol, indexer

We are trying to build custom indexer client with the newest near-lake-farmwork-py, but always stuck at `await streamer_messages_queue.get()`. Then we try to access those default S3 bucket in [code](https://github.com/frolvanya/near-lake-framework-py/blob/93a9d3d069679169c21902a54fa83a03b21153bb/src/near_lake_framework/__init__.py#L25) with our own AWS S3 credentials, it says: `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records`.
So we wonder is there any step we miss, that register our own AWS Access Key to the bucket explicitly or is there any public key to do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS documentation for the error message you posted](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-key-error/), it seems that the access key you created does not exist (either revoked or mistyped).

> So we wonder is there any step we miss, that register our own AWS Access Key to the bucket explicitly or is there any public key to do that?

Nope, no extra steps are needed from the NEAR Lake side, as AWS buckets are already configured with "requester pays" policy. There is something wrong with your AWS setup (not specific to the NEAR Lake buckets).

As mentioned in the [NEAR Lake documentation](https://near-indexers.io/tutorials/lake/credentials), follow [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) to get AWS access keys.

Comment: Thanks, will re-apply AWS access key to try again.